# What is the daily review queue limit for docs?

Tags: support, edits, documentation, rate-limiting

I just got told I cannot review anymore topic proposals today:

[image]

What is the daily review queue limit for Documentation?

Comment: Dumb question: Where is this queue? I'm not seeing it on http://stackoverflow.com/review

Comment: @Frank There isn't a 'queue' for it, but you'll trigger it in Documentation when you review topic proposals

Comment: Related feature request: [Increase reviews limit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330092/increase-reviews-limit)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Currently, you're limited to 30 reviews of proposed topic changes per day.

Comment: Quill did 38 today.

Comment: @nicael Quill is special.

Comment: Actually he did 40, @nicael. Not all of them count toward this limit though.

Comment: Which do, then? And where are the remaining two, I could count just 38... Or I can't count properly?

Comment: At least a couple are deleted, and several are kinda in limbo; seems it has kind of a weird way of counting these, but perhaps it will make more sense after more coffee.

Comment: @Shog9: I just submitted a feature [request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330092/increase-reviews-limit) to increase the count.