# Docs.SO needs a review queue

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, documentation

Now that the masses are allowed to make documentation changes, reviewing their pending requests is more important than ever. The number of edits jumped by several orders of magnitude across the board, and we're getting lots of crap edits that need to be declined or significantly improved.

However, if you look at the pending edits list for a tag, you can't tell which ones you've reviewed and which ones you haven't.

We either need the ability to cull those you've already reviewed, or we need a real review queue per-tag that works like the Stack Exchange review queue.

Also, I just found out that there's a limit to how much you can review in a day. That's... a very bad thing, especially given the massive degrading of edit quality coupled with the massive increase in the number of edits.

Comment: Oh, how much is the limit then? I didn't hit that one yet ...

Comment: [It's reasonably high](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328474/what-is-the-daily-review-queue-limit-for-docs/328485#328485), @rene. Just an insane number of people submitting edits right now, and throttling is pretty generous.

Comment: @Shog9: I don't believe that 30 is "reasonably high" for what Docs.SO is doing. On SO, if you have enough reputation, your edits don't need to be reviewed. On Docs.SO, they *always* need review. So you have to "waste" reviews on people who actually know what they're talking about.

Comment: It can be changed if necessary; that said, only 14 people - about 1% of reviewers - have hit that cap so far today; it'll take a few days to get a feel for where this should be, how many reviews are necessary, etc. We have *some* idea of where this should fall based on suggested edits, but as you note they're not quite the same thing.

Comment: Never mind the needs of the "average" reviewer, why is there a review cap _at all_? It already doesn't make sense for edit suggestions on Q&A, it makes less than no sense when literally nothing can be done _without review_. That's fully half of the contribution you make to working on Docs.

Comment: I'm in the 1% now of users that hit the cap, needed two more...

Comment: @Shog9: It should be noted that people are hitting the review cap even though 1) Docs.SO hasn't been online for 24 hours, and 2) we still have ~5 hours before the cap gets reset. So I'd say that's a strong indicator that the cap needs to be expanded, if not removed entirely. I agree with Josh; it's not clear what kind of behavior we are attempting to stop by capping reviews.

Comment: I expect reviewers fatigue to be the reason ...

Comment: Plenty of people hit the normal review caps every day, @Nicol. That's very much intended - you don't necessarily want the same people reviewing *everything*, especially when there's a very large amount of *everything*. Quite honestly, 30/day is pretty high for anything beyond trivial changes - I don't expect most folks to sustain that. Eventually, we're gonna need something akin to privileged edits.

Comment: I am also waiting days for reviews. Now I have 10 pending and can't add any more documentation!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We're working on a review queue that functions very similar to the Suggested Edits queue in Q&A.

A rough mockup is [mentioned in this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329557/documentation-update-july-25th?cb=1). More to come soon.

Comment: do you plan to have [meta-tag:review-audits] in this queue?

Comment: @gnat short answer — probably but not necessarily in the first release. I agree that's an important feature, but it will be much quicker in the short-term to release a review queue without it then progressively improve with audits after we get the MVP out.