# Another example of why Documentation should require more than one reviewer

Tags: discussion, documentation

Although it isn't a huge addition I do believe my initial proposal ([seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/12096?draftId=11969)) added useful clarification to the topic.

It was later rejected with the response: `Contains factually incorrect information.
== is called the equality operator`.

Feeling pretty crazy at the time I decided to modify my justifications slightly and submit the request [one more time](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/12808?draftId=12554) in the hopes that maybe I'd get a different reviewer.

But alas it was not meant to be, this time the rejection response (from the same user) was: `Very poor addition and incorrect.`

So I moved on, like I said, it wasn't a huge addition by any means.

Then today I hop on SO to see that [this change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/23900) was later approved by the exact same person that had twice rejected my change request with virtually the exact same contents.

What have I gathered from this small chain of events? We need more than 1 reviewer for documentation changes. I'm sure plenty of others have already experienced a similar situation and it's not likely to change in the current format. What do you guys think, am I way off-base here or is this a legitimate concern?

The same concern [is voiced here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328784) but without a clear example of the type of tomfoolery that is likely to continue if the current system remains in place.

Comment: Well one thing the other edit has that yours doesn't it is actually says which one is which.

Comment: Similar thing happend to me http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328968/how-are-rejection-conflicts-handled-in-documentation

Comment: Maybe a 4 votes approval with weight from the SO tag, gold badges in tag worth 4 votes (approve or reject immediately), silver worth 3, bronze worth 2 and no badge worth 1, this could smooth the review while ensuring there's a knowledgeable peer reviewing. Maybe prevent two review in a row of same topic change by same author from same reviewer too to avoid this kind of rejection and enforcing others reviewer for thes econd proposal ?

Comment: @Tensibai I agree, I was thinking of a very similar approach - where higher rep or higher tag-count users' votes carried more weight in the approval process. This would definitely be an improvement to the current process.

Comment: More complex, but perhaps better, would be to tie the "worth 4 votes" to the user's rep _in the tags associated with the item_.