# How should I communicate with the reviewer who rejected my Documentation change?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, documentation

My change on Documentation was [rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/9317?draftId=9074). I disagree with the reason of rejection.

How can I communicate with the reviewer to explain my point of view or clarify his point of view?

Are any links/ comments area available for such communication?

Can they be added in a future?

The only process I see is to do some changes and submit a new draft, but it will be reviewed by other person (which may be good :). It should be better way to do it.

On normal Stack Overflow site reviews are only small part of activities. On Documentation everything should be reviewed and also reviewers can be less experienced with low reputation (see [an example here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328972/another-example-of-why-documentation-should-require-more-than-one-reviewer?rq=1)). So there will be many more cases when communication between author and reviewer will be needed.

Comment: Why do you disagree? The comment is correct; the information you added is already in the relevant example and not so relevant in the context of using them like ordinary class methods.

Comment: We need more ways to comment/discuss changes!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: _This question on meta is about procedure to communicate with reviewers, not about particular rejection._  Regarding particular change: I want to say that even extension methods can be called as normal static methods, it is **not recommended**-ReSharper shows code smell warning and suggests to change to use as instance syntax

Comment: What would be your end-goal? What will be the effect on reviewers, like my self, that try to reject as many changes as possible if they get harassed by doing so?

Comment: @rene: When you write answer or comment, you expect that other people will reply to you. When you reject someone's suggestion, people should be able to discuss your reasoning (asking for clarification or proving you are wrong)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim yes, that is correct for comment and answer but the reviewers (except for dupe hammers) cannot be contacted /pinged directly. I don't see why that should change for docs.

Comment: @rene: on normal SO reviews are only small part of activities. On docs everything should be reviewed and also reviewers can be less experienced (with low rep). So  it will be much more reasons for communication between author and reviewer.

Comment: Behind every wikipedia page, there's a *"talk"* page that allows contributors to discuss the accuracy, completeness, proposed additions, disputed content of the page. Seems like we should have something similar here.

Comment: There is an 'add a comment' button under proposed changes, even your rejected one. I assume you can reply there, @naming the person who rejected your comment, discuss alternatives and then press the 'Improve Draft' button to make changes? (I guess, as we are in Beta, some of these features may be new).

Comment: We need something like a talk page. For every tag, topic, and example.

Comment: @AliBeadle: I haven't try it, but I don't think, that reviewers will be notified if you will mention by '@name' in comment. At least auto-resolution in browser doesn't recognize reviewers names. Anyway it's a good  and consistent to SO way to implement. You can put it as an answer.

Comment: I've seen an example where my massive (feeling) documentation page was rejected because one code example was claimed not to work. I retried it and it worked, but too late, it's already in the dustbin of rejection, with no way of me telling the rejecter that they were wrong.

Comment: Solution proposed: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329880/commenting-after-approval-and-pinging-reviewers-of-a-documentation-change-propos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Ali Beadle](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2466193/ali-beadle) in [comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329103/how-should-i-communicate-with-the-reviewer-who-rejected-my-documentation-change/330308#comment371850_329103) suggested to use an '**add a comment**' button under proposed changes.

Currently reviewers are not notified if you will mention them by '@name' in the comment.   Adding such notifications will improve communication between documentation authors and reviewers.

See similar suggestion in [Commenting after approval and pinging reviewers of a Documentation change proposal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329880/commenting-after-approval-and-pinging-reviewers-of-a-documentation-change-propos?noredirect=1&lq=1)