# Can a documentation review message be flagged?

Tags: support, documentation

I have seen that documentation does not have for now a way to communicate with the reviewer who rejected a change as in [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329103/how-should-i-communicate-with-the-reviewer-who-rejected-my-documentation-change), but on the same principle, I was unable to find a way to flag a review message.

What if a reviewer is rude, or chatty, is there a way to flag this, as it is for comments of a post?

Comment: I would suggest, in the case the comment is extreme, flagging a post outside of documentation. Explain in the "in need of moderator attention" field what the problem is and link to the proposed change. I don't know if this should necessarily be done for smaller issues with comments, but if someone is being outrageously out of control in the documentation review comments...

Comment: @Kendra this is a workaround, but I guess it will be effective, it is a good idea if it will be ever necessary!

Comment: Please don't worry, I already reported your **5 duplicate proposed changes** where you completely ignored rejection reasons, didn't fix anything suggested in the comments and just kept resubmitting the same text. My flag was marked as helpful, so please make sure you still have editing privileges.

Comment: @Squindward I am not worried and I also don't think that your comment is somehow related to this question. Have a good day!