# What is the policy of approval/rejection votes when review changes on Documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, approval

I proposed a change on Documentation beta and it was approved by one person and rejected by another. However, the final resolution is "rejected". Why?

There are not enough details regarding this on [the help page for proposed changes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/documentation-proposed-changes).

Shouldn't it wait for at least one more "reject" vote?

Comment: Do you have a link to this edit?

Comment: @AstroCB: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/9317?draftId=9074

Comment: I'm actually not sure about how this works anymore; I thought two approvals/rejections were required to make a decision, but my last few changes have been approved with one vote and I noticed I am able to approve changes single-handedly. I don't think it has anything to do with reputation, because if that were the case, the approve vote would have won on that edit. Also, I can't seem to find any specifics for proposed changes anywhere (on the main site at least).

Comment: I've had the opposite! (1 approval, 1 reject, it was approved...)

Comment: There is an official answer -[2 votes for  rejection and 1 for approval](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328785), but my example contradicts to it.

Comment: Seems like a bug. @kevin-montrose can say the actual thing.