# Do not allow only one user to approve documentation edits that have already been rejected by another reviewer

Tags: feature-request, documentation

The other day, I rejected a revision request that contained false information; only to see the same revision approved by another user and incorporated into the docs a day later.  When one user has rejected an edit, that indicates that there is (probably) something wrong with the edit, and approval should be harder as a result.

Instead of allowing an edit to go through on a 1-1 vote, I'd propose requiring a 2-1 or 3-1 vote in favor of the edit (or, at the very least, hold the edit to a higher bar of scrutiny in some manner or other) if the initial reviewer rejects.

Comment: Well, you can't have it both ways [Proposed changes should not be able to be rejected by one person](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328784)

Comment: Deleting an entire topic with one approval feels weird too. Even more so when you were the one that requested the improvement. Shouldn't that be vetted by more people?

Comment: It's easy to have it both ways; the same was proposed for suggested edits on Q&A: [you just require a _difference_ of 2 between accept and reject votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219916/implement-a-tennis-rule-for-approving-suggested-edits?noredirect=1&lq=1) before determining an outcome.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I would be more comfortable with requiring a *factor* of 2. I mean, if you have 10 rejects and 12 accepts votes, it's just a timing factor that the 12th accept vote made it before the 11th reject one. Or there are statistics ways to determine the "mood" of a crowd from a sample... and notably to determine that the current sample is not wide enough to draw any conclusive outcome from it. But just a difference of 2 is not enough.

Comment: You can suggest shorter "Do not allow only one user to approve documentation edits".(full stop)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In Q/A, prior to a question getting closed, you can see total close vote count and count per reason, why not similar in Documentation?

I would propose that if a rejection exists that the comments for that rejection are visible to next reviewer and that they are aware of someone else having concerns instead of blind voting.

The actual user who left first rejection could be left as anonymous until final tally is resolved. I lean on the side of full transparency where some others feel blind voting is the proper way

This same issue has been raised by others who regretted approving something when they got to see final tally and were able to read comments that made them look at the edit in a different light. At that point there is no way to undo an approval.

Comment: What might be a rationale for keeping them anonymous? A reviewer shouldn't want to shy away from discussing the stuff they review...

Comment: @Frank I raised this similar debate elsewhere and got pointed at [Secret Ballot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_ballot) and arguments that everyone should be objective when reviewing and not persuaded by actions of others.  I'm actually on your side for full transparency

Comment: "that rejection" > It will be "other" 90% of the time in my case.

Comment: @Knu not sure what the point is.

Comment: As a semi-work around, one can add a comment to the proposal stating why you rejected it (helps others see it and adds a visible "1 comment" note in the queue) - I try to do this but do tend to get overwhelmed by bad quality proposals and kinda taper off

Comment: I don't like that when I make some constructive criticism in a rejection comment (but the approval goes through), no one ever sees / looks at it. As here: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/proposed/changes/64587 Kind of goes against the whole idea of collaboratively editing. Really, the author of the edit should get a ping as soon as there's a rejection vote. And maybe rejection comments should be upgraded to improvement requests when they are overridden.

Comment: @frank you could have added a comment to the review (at the bottom of the example while its in review). That way others would be able to see it.

Comment: @Daniel Yeah, that's the way to go for now.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is better here than in my [closed question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330045/approving-half-rejected-proposals-should-be-more-difficult)

My proposed solution for this: **a proposal should need at least 1 more approvals than rejections to be considered approved**

Maybe proposals reaching 10 approvals and rejects could be locked, and only decided by high tag score members to stop chicken fights over proposals.

**Pro:**

- a controversial proposal would get the attention required
- it would take at least 2 roboreviewer to approve a proposal that has already 1 reject - less clutter

**Con:**

- approve-reject battles perhaps - until cap is reached

Opinions?

Answer (score -1):

What about taking into account the expertise level of reviewers for raising the stakes?

Maybe decisions taken by a user having some badge level should only be modified by same of better tag badge level user?

Something like:

**Scenario 1:**

- No tag badge reject
- Any other user may balance rejection

**Scenario 2:**

- Bronze tag badge reject
- Need bronze of upper badge owner to balance rejection

The idea behind that proposal is that tag badge ownership more or less reflects the expertise level. Otherwise how could we know who is right and if the content should really be accepted or rejected?

Comment: This doesn't work for a couple reasons: 1) on some tags, it's hard to find good, answerable questions. This could be because the tag is relatively small, or it could be because a lot of the questions are duplicate/low quality. So someone who is on SO and has low rep _could_ know what they're doing in that tag and just not have a tag badge. 2) If a new user who is expert in that field starts, it'll take some time to get a tag badge. Same outcome as 1. 3) Gold tag badge does not always mean expert. Could be, they found the easy questions to answer. (Not saying this is usually the case!)

Comment: @Kendra: what you pointed out is true, but that does not imply that my suggestion doesn't work, merely that the behavior I suggested is not perfect. From a relative standpoint, I still believe that a user with a tag badge is more likely to be an expert of the subject that someone else. Of course we could do better and find a way to give actual expertise level badges on taged subjects. A trouble is that the most well known efficient ways of doing this are very alien for StackOverflow: peer cooptation (think followers), or showing external credentials (think MOOP and certification).