# Approving half-rejected proposals should be more difficult

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation, documentation-proposals

Small proposal for the proposals: **a proposal should need at least 1 more approvals than rejections to be considered approved**

Maybe proposals reaching 10 approvals and rejects could be locked, and only decided by high tag score members to stop chicken fights over proposals.

**Pro:**

- a controversial proposal would get the attention required
- it would take at least 2 roboreviewer to approve a proposal that has already 1 reject - less clutter

**Con:**

- approve-reject battles perhaps - until cap is reached

Opinions?

Comment: @DavidG sorry, I tried, but for some reason I didn't find that question when I created this one...

Comment: No worries, funnily enough, both these questions are on the side bar right now :)

Comment: @DavidG Yep, that does indeed looks funny :) At least it seems I'm not alone with my perceived problem... Should I move this proposal-proposal to said topic as an answer?

Comment: They are working on a review queue system. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328645/docs-so-needs-a-review-queue

Comment: @Timothy that is great to know, and IMHO this proposal could be applied to that too, about how that should work...