# Lift the Docs review limit for "trusted" users

Tags: feature-request, documentation, rate-limiting

The [daily limit of 30 reviews](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328474/what-is-the-daily-review-queue-limit-for-docs) feels very restrictive, especially just after the docs release when there are tons of changes being proposed.

Can we consider raising/removing the limit for "trusted" users (some level of rep, or a gold tag badge, or another measure of trust)?

Comment: Related: [Docs.SO needs a review queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328645)