# Increase reviews limit

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, documentation, documentation-proposals

Just now, I got this error message again, when voting on a proposed draft:

> [image]

Basically, I'm out of votes.

I don't know what the daily limit is, but I hit it (at least) 2 days in a row now.
I'd like to see the limit increased, as there's plenty of junk edit being submitted that really should be rejected.

Furthermore, this message is only shown *after* you fill in a rejection reason, and clicking *"Reject Change"*.
I'd like to see this message *before* I take the effort to fill in a reason.

Comment: It's 30, fwiw. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328485/

Comment: A scaling of the number of votes based on reputation would be ideal here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lift the Docs review limit for "trusted" users](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328710/lift-the-docs-review-limit-for-trusted-users)

Comment: I disagree, reviewing should be spread over as many users as possible. Perhaps instead increase the rep limit for contributions or lower the contribution limit, etc... Just today I have seen a user with 1 rep creating a new unneeded topic.

Comment: @2501 and a 100-500 rep user approving it? No? I mean that's how we feel.